# How to send a file from client to server in Java

Tags: java, image, send

How do I send an image to a server for post-processing?
From server to client is easy, but when it comes to the opposite, which is the best way to proceed?

Comment: you mean when the server has to send it back?

Comment: Yeah, what kind of client/server? HTTP? plain sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use FTP. Use Apache FTP libraries.

**Client side**: Jakarta commons net:
http://commons.apache.org/net/

**Server side:** Apache FTP Server: http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/

Answer (score 0):

You don't terminate the connection, but send the processed image through the outputstream of the connection on the server side.